# How to parse this type of json and set in UITableView cell

Tags: ios, json, swift, jsonparser

How to set this json in a tableView.

```json
{
   "page":0,
   "pageSize":5,
   "totalPageCount":16,
   "wkda":{
      "020":"Abarth",
      "040":"Alfa Romeo",
      "042":"Alpina",
      "043":"Alpine",
      "057":"Aston Martin"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a struct which represents your data

```
struct YourObjectName: Codable {
    let page, pageSize, totalPageCount: Int
    let wkda: [String: String]
}
```

When getting your data from the server, parse your json into your newly created object, and store that object somewhere in your viewController.

```
let yourObject = try? newJSONDecoder().decode(YourObjectName.self, from: jsonData)
```

When configuring the tableView, set the number of rows based on your data:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return yourObject.count // Or something similar, based on your needs
}
```

Finally use your data to populate the cells:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SomeIdentifier", for: indexPath)
   // Populate your cell
   return cell
}
```

Also I encourage you to read a bit about TableView. Here is a good source to start: [TableViews](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/CreateATableView.html)